# This assignment is designed to explore linked lists so you will implement a singly linked-list to hold a collection of bids loaded from a CSV file

Tags: c++, pointers

I need help please It keeps giving me the same number and not a different one.

```cpp
Bid LinkedList::Search(string bidId) {
    // FIXME (6): Implement search logic

    // special case if matching node is the head
        // make head point to the next node in the list
        //decrease size count
        //return

    // start at the head of the list

    // keep searching until end reached with while loop (next != nullptr
        // if the current node matches, return it
        // else current node is equal to next node

     //return bid
    Node* temp = head;
    Node* holder = new Node;
    holder->bid.bidId = "";
    while (temp != nullptr) {
        cout << temp->bid.bidId << endl;
        if (temp->bid.bidId == bidId) {
            return temp->bid;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
        return holder->bid;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can tell you that the code has a memory leak. Not sure why you have this: `Node* holder = new Node;` This code is not a [mcve]

Comment: I did two Node since if I only used one the code throw me an exception.

Comment: I tried this Node* current = head;
    //loop over each node looking for a match
    while (current->next != nullptr) {
        if (current->bid.bidId.compare(bidId) == 0) {
            return current->bid;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}
But it didn't work

Comment: You have a return inside the while loop. So you are not actually traversing anything.

Comment: That is a good point `return holder->bid;` needs to be after the loop.

Comment: What do you do, if the list is empty? Furthermore note that `holder` is only accessed in the initialization and in the `return` statement. The content of the list does not have any influence on the value returned (only, on if a value is returned at all...)

Comment: I had it out side but for some reason it keeps getting the same number Node* temp = head;
    Node* holder = new Node;
    holder->bid.bidId = "";
    while (temp->next != nullptr) {
        if (temp->bid.bidId.compare(bidId) == 0) {
            return temp->bid;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return holder->bid;
}

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit the question instead. Also I am pretty sure that no one  (outside your class mates) can solve the problem given only the current code. We can point out some issues but we don't have the full picture.

Comment: What are you supposed to return if the bid is not found?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. The code while loop should look for a different number so it would be availed to find another bid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove everything with a `holder`. And at the end throw an exception when nothing was found. Alternatively return `std::optional<Bid>`.